# Display friend post according to the friend connected to each other?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql frnd_request and nsm_post i want to show the post according to the user share post to primary school mate , secondary school mate etc.

frnd_request table referece is the column from which user are connected to each other.
    table structure below

```
1 id    

2 user_id   

3 frnd_id   

4 status    

5 referece  (how friend are connected to each other like primay, secondary school mate)

6 confirmation  

7 note

8 date
```

nsm_post post table show_to is the field which define which friend group of logged in user can see this post.

```
1   id  

2   uid (user id of user who posted this post)

3   post    


4   ip  



5   show_to (to which friend group post will be display)

6   Img_video_name  



7   date
```

Comment: Your question needs to give a LOT more details. We need to see what relevant columns are in the tables and how those columns relate to one another. Then we need to understand what you WANT to see and we need to see what you've already tried and what's not working about what you've tried.

Comment: now i have post the table strunture and all things

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nsm_post.post 
FROM frnd_request, nsm_post
WHERE frnd_request.user_id = nsm_post.uid
```

This should work. 
I guess what you are trying to do is restricting the posts to the user's school mates. But this is not really possible with your current table structure. 
You have to setup an additional table like this:

primary | uid1 | uid2 | type

0 | 10004 | 10005 | school mate

Comment: I've changed it according to your structure. This should work now.

Comment: its giving the repeated row also i want the data according to the user share with whom like primary, secondary school mate

Comment: @sujit this isn't really possible with your table structure. Check my answer once again.

Comment: Nothing is impossible :) But it's really really really a bad (a terrible) practice to create a messy database structure and then adapt the code to it all the time.
Think about other developers. They'll get completely insane if they have to develop something with your database.

http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: ok can please tell me the database structure how to table should be relate.

Comment: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php This should help.

Ask yourself the questions: 

- Which objects are involved (users, posts and so on)

- Which information do I need (for the single object)

- How are they related to each other

- n to n relations have to be setup in an additional  table

Comment: how create relate table in this situation

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561   Section: Many to Many Relationship